# Coproducts and products are the same

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

I was playing aroudn with finite dimensional vector spaces, and I found that coproducts are the same thing in $\textbf{FinDiVec}$.

What other categories exist where this is the case, and what are some criteria for thist to be true.

Comment: Somewhat relatedly is that, if your category has a zero object, there is a canonical map from coproduct to product (by noting the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(\coprod_i X_i,\prod_j Y_j)\cong \prod_{i,j}\operatorname{Hom}(X_i,Y_j)$ given by the universal properties for products and coproducts, then, when $X=Y$, choosing the identity map in $\operatorname{Hom}(X_i,X_i)$ and the zero map for all other homomorphisms). This map is a natural isomorphism for finite (co)products of vector spaces, an injection for infinite (co)products of vector spaces, and a surjection in the category of groups.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a blog post, *[Meditation on semiadditive categories](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/a-meditation-on-semiadditive-categories/)*, which answers this question in detail. The short answer:

> In a category with both finite products and finite coproducts, finite products and coproducts coincide (it is a bit trickier than you might think to say precisely what this means; there's an obvious way of doing it which is wrong, and the correct way of doing it requires handling the 0-ary case separately and first) if *and only if* the category is [enriched over](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) commutative monoids.

Most examples in practice are enriched over abelian groups, and most examples that people care about in practice are [abelian categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category). This includes examples like vector spaces, modules over a ring, sheaves of abelian groups on topological spaces, quasicoherent sheaves on schemes, etc.